# Reading encoded XML tags Through RSS feed

Tags: c#, xml, rss, syndication-feed

I have been trying to read XML file through my RSS link. I am using 
SyndicationFeed class . The issue is that I am unable to read some of the tags due to protection.

```
<item>
    <title>.......................</title>
    <link>................................</link>
    <comments>.........................................</comments>
    <pubDate>.................</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Abc]]></dc:creator>
    <category><![CDATA[Sports]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[XYZ]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Nba]]></category>

    <guid isPermaLink="false">......................</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[LOS ANGELES: NBA officiating has become too strict <a href="https://example.com/" 
        title="Read more" >...</a>]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>...</p>
        <p> .........................................</p>
        <p>................................................</p>
        <p>............................................................</p>
        <p>..............................................</p> ]]>
    </content:encoded>
    <wfw:commentRss>https://example.com/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

I want to read all xml nodes.
Here is my code

```
var feedUrl = textBox1.Text;// "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast";
using (var feedReader = XmlReader.Create(feedUrl))
{
    var feedContent = SyndicationFeed.Load(feedReader);
    if (null == feedContent) return;
       foreach (var item in feedContent.Items)
       {
            String abc_Title = item.Title.Text;
            String desc = item.Summary.Text; 
       }
 }
```